# Will Launch succeed if I start the Art just before Daze wears off?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-3

Let's say an enemy has been inflicted with Daze. Then, just before Daze wears off I try to continue the Art Combo by using an art that inflicts Launch. Will the Launch status succeed as long as I activate a launch-inflicting Art before Daze wears off? Or can the Daze status wear off while I'm mid-attack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't enough to start a Launch Art while Daze is active. The Launch-inflicting art needs to hit the enemy before Daze wears off.

I tested this using the training drill for Launch. I waited to use the launching art until the Daze status almost ran out. The Daze wore off during the attack animation, the enemy was not launched, and I failed the drill.